# Difference between iris$Sepal.Width & "Sepal.Width" in []

Tags: r

```
subset(iris, Sepal.Width  > 4 & Sepal.Length > 5, select = c(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length,Species))
```

I was checking out the subset function but I thought the same thing can be accomplished easier so why remember a new function.

So i wrote the below code to replicate the above subset function

1)

```
 iris["Sepal.Width" > 4 & "Sepal.Length" > 5,c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length","Species")]
```

But the & condition is not working in here and when I checked the below code and it worked

2)

```
 iris[iris$Sepal.Width > 4 & iris$Sepal.Length > 5,c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length","Species")]
```

Please explain

- How code 1) & 2) are different I expected both 1) & 2) to give same
  result.
- Since we have code 2) why should we use subset function? Any
  scenario where subset function is better?

Thanks

Comment: This question is about R programming and has been flagged for migration to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're comparing the string `Sepal.Width` to the number `4`, not the values of the column of the same name. So these will always be `TRUE`:

```
> "Sepal.Width" > 4
[1] TRUE

> "Sepal.Length" > 5
[1] TRUE
```

So you're for `iris[TRUE, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length","Species")]` which returns all rows for the selected columns. I personally prefer using `subset`.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain why subset is better?

Comment: Mostly for readability, but also consistency since `subset` can work on multiple different data formats (data.frame, matrix, list, etc).